# How to handle dynamic response from dialogflow agent through botium-cli

Tags: command-line-interface, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

My bot is live on website. Chat bot collect user data and such as name, email and project requirements. These intents are structured through contexts. When user gives an input for name, Bot response is "Hi $name, what is your email id ?" and when enters email id then bot response is "what is your project requirements ?"

As we can see, every intent has dynamic response. How can we handle these dynamic responses in botium-cli

Answer (score 0):

In Botium you can configure the *Matching Mode* for doing the text assertions. The default setting is *includeLowerCase*, which actually means *case insensitive substring matching*. It could be used like this:

```
#me
my name is john

#bot
what is your email id
```

This will just match a part of the bot response, if this is acceptable assertions you have to decide yourself.

In your case, the matching mode *regexp* maybe would be a better choice: you can use regular expressions then, for example:

```
#me
my name is john

#bot
Hi \w+, what is your email id \?
```

You can read more about it [in the Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#Scripting-Capabilities).

Be aware that by default, Botium *normalizes* all texts before doing comparisions, when using regular expressions, you most likely want to disable this (see [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT)).

For exploring other options for dealing with dynamic content in Botium, namely:

- Utterances files
- Scripting Memory
- Asserters and Logic Hooks

please consult the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491664/Botium+Scripting+-+BotiumScript).